# VMs reset after suspend

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

Sometimes, when I close and open the notebook lid, my VMs are like this. It appears locked but actually what happened is that all the apps got closed and I to unlock the screen and reopen everything.

Both host and guest are ubuntu 20.04, and I'm using virt-manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try these ways:

---

On the first boot after installation, before logging into the machine, drop into a TTY session login and remove the gstreamer-vaapi application. Then the user can login to the machine and not have the possibility of this particular login crash loop.

At the GUI Login screen:

1. Ctrl + Alt + F1 to enter a TTY.
2. Login with your username and password and do the following:

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi
> sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
> ```

3. Ctrl + Alt + F7 will bring you back to the GUI Login and you can proceed as you would normally.

---

If using KVM or QEMU Virtual Machines please use `virtio` as your video adapter.
If using Virtual Box please use `VMVGA` as your video adapter.

---

Original text is [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/20-04-workaround-for-xorg-crashes-to-login-prompt-in-virtual-machines/21368).

It was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior of GNOME.
You can change that preference as follows:

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Tweaks.
2. Click Tweaks to open the application.
3. Select the General tab.
4. Switch the Suspend when laptop lid is closed switch to off.
5. Close the Tweaks window

.

Comment: this is not suspend, this is a bug that is making all apps be closed

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Do you tried the above steps?

Comment: yes. If it were a suspend then it would still have the apps opened, but they are actually closed as the system rebooted